# Click Button not click through to Table Row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with which I've implemented an accordion effect. One of the cells has a `<button>`. If I click the button, the button's onclick happens, but the table row also takes the click (which expands/collapses the accordion). How do I prevent the click from going through the button to the table row?

This is my click function:

```
$("#accordiontable tr.accordion-parent").click(function () {
    $(this).nextUntil(".accordion-parent").toggle();
    $(this).find(".accordion-arrow").toggleClass("ui-icon-circle-triangle-e");
    $(this).find(".accordion-arrow").toggleClass("ui-icon-circle-triangle-s");
});
```

And one of the  cells has a `<button onclick="DoCommand()">` in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to get e.stopPropagation to work, it still expanded/collapsed the row when I clicked the button. I figured there's got to be a way to see exactly what was clicked on. I found https://api.jquery.com/event.target/ and used it like this:

```
$("#accordiontable tr.accordion-parent").click(function (e) {
    var target = $(e.target);
    if (!target.is("button")) {
        $(this).nextUntil(".accordion-parent").toggle();
        $(this).find(".accordion-arrow").toggleClass("ui-icon-circle-triangle-e");
        $(this).find(".accordion-arrow").toggleClass("ui-icon-circle-triangle-s");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Call jQuery's event.stopPropagation() function.

https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

```
$("#accordiontable tr.accordion-parent").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).nextUntil(".accordion-parent").toggle();
    $(this).find(".accordion-arrow").toggleClass("ui-icon-circle-triangle-e");
    $(this).find(".accordion-arrow").toggleClass("ui-icon-circle-triangle-s");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add e.stopPropagation(); to your first click handler.

```
$("#accordiontable tr.accordion-parent").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).nextUntil(".accordion-parent").toggle();
    $(this).find(".accordion-arrow").toggleClass("ui-icon-circle-triangle-e");
    $(this).find(".accordion-arrow").toggleClass("ui-icon-circle-triangle-s");
});
```

Comment: Spelling mistake: propAgation